# Is it safe to offer PHP Laravel Blade as a template solution for public input?

Tags: php, laravel, security, laravel-blade

I'm trying to offer to the users (will be open to the internet, anyone can register) a WYSYWIG editor where users can input BLADE code to code their pages.

I want to provide them with the ability to create small functions to parse arrays/strings so I saw the @php tag of Blade useful for this.

My question: I can't find anywhere if this is like a sandboxed environment where only certain "safe" functions can be run or if this is more like an eval() and thus allowing people to basically inject PHP code to destroy the server and/or pull sensitive content?

I tried testing running basic commands with blade, but I would like a professional opinion on whether it's a bad idea regarding security (like, know exploits or other performance issues)

Thank you

Comment: Set it up and try to break it with raw PHP --  That will be your definitive answer.

Comment: no blade is not for this at all ... blade compiles files into PHP and it allows for PHP (since it only parses the blade parts into PHP), there is no way to restrict anything .... you could look into twig perhaps

Answer (score 1):

Having a WYSIWIG open to the public on it's own has it's own challenges, because you will have to look into sanitizing the input/output otherwise you'll be opening yourself up to XSS attacks.

Allowing PHP code as well is obviously going to have lots of security risks, I wouldn't advise it personally - but it is technically possible. There are other online php sandbox editiors available, how exactly they secure themselves is beyond me. There are a lot of clever tricks that can be done, trying to whitelist or blacklist functions you deem as safe/unsafe is probably the way to go - but I still personally wouldn't feel comfortable implementing something like that. You may think you've covered all possible attacks, but it only takes one that bypasses what you've setup to essentially take over your server.